# Unable to parse Ctype structure in python received from socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, struct, ctypes

I have a python client connected to an embedded server, which we communicate using c structure, am able to send the structure to the server and he is able to receive and parse my structure, the socket response is again a structure which I am unable to parse, there is no change in the structure format.

```
from ctypes import *

class CommonMessage(Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [
            ("sof", c_uint), ("request_id", c_uint),
            ("interface", c_uint), ("msg_type", c_uint),
            ("response", c_uint),
            ("data_len", c_int), 
            ("data", c_ubyte * msg_length)
        ]

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.98.64', 7000)
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.sendall(message_proto)
sz = sizeof(message_proto)
data = sock.recv(sz)
print(data)
b'\xcc\xdd\xee\xff~Y\xd4\x0b\x02\xb9\xa9\x00i\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
parsed_data = CommonMessage.from_buffer_copy(data)
```

while trying to parse the struct data getting an error

**Buffer size too small (24 instead of at least 93 bytes)**

Please do help....

Comment: where is `msg_length` defined?

Comment: TCP is byte-oriented.  You have to verify that you received at least 93 bytes (in this case) before parsing it.  Better to design a protocol to send the size of the data and then the data...buffer your received data and extract only complete messages.

Comment: message length is the length of the string

 msg_length = len(serialized_string)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the *CTypes* doc page: [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There's a design problem here. Imagine the following scenario: the other part sends the header + data (2 times) like:

1. 15 bytes (`data_len* = 15`), and 15 extra bytes after the ones corresponding to the *struct*
2. 25 bytes (`data_len = 25`), and 25 extra bytes after the ones corresponding to the *struct*

**You can't model that scenario with a *CommonMessage* defined *statically***. What you need to do, is split it in 2 (*header* and *data*) sections, and every time you want to get a message:

1. Read the header
2. Look in the header for *data_len*
3. Read **exactly** *data_len* bytes as data

This is the general solution, which works for all such cases. If there are particularities in your situation, other approaches - which are either simpler (from code *PoV*) either faster - could be used, but those will only work for those particularities. But since the question doesn't mention any such particularities (it's not even a *MCVE* - 
 as the code doesn't compile *OOTB*), I'm going to stick with the general solution. 
Note that it's the same as [[SO]: multiple send from server to client python
 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615187/multiple-send-from-server-to-client-python/30615690#30615690).

*code00.py*:

```py
import sys
import ctypes


#              b"\xcc\xdd\xee\xff~Y\xd4\x0b\x02\xb9\xa9\x00i\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"  # Original buffer
INPUT_BUFFER = b"\xcc\xdd\xee\xff~Y\xd4\x0b\x02\xb9\xa9\x00i\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05Dummy TextIGNORED PART"  # At the end, there are bytes for data
#                                                                                         ^ - Modified data length to 15


class CommonMessageHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("sof", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("request_id", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("interface", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("msg_type", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("response", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("data_len", ctypes.c_int),
    ]


def print_ctypes_instance_info(obj, indent="", metadata="", max_array_items=10, indent_increment="    "):
    if metadata:
        print("{:s}{:s}: {:}".format(indent, metadata, obj))
    else:
        print("{:s}[{:}]: {:}".format(indent, type(obj), obj))
    if isinstance(obj, ctypes.Structure):

        for field_name, field_type in obj._fields_:
            print_ctypes_instance_info(getattr(obj, field_name),indent=indent + indent_increment, metadata="[{:}] {:s}".format(field_type, field_name))
    elif isinstance(obj, ctypes.Array):

        if max_array_items < len(obj):
            items_len, extra_line = max_array_items, True
        else:
            items_len, extra_line = len(obj), False
        for idx in range(items_len):
            print_ctypes_instance_info(obj[idx], indent=indent + indent_increment, metadata="[{:d}]".format(idx))
        if extra_line:
            print("{:s}...".format(indent + indent_increment))


def get_instance_from_buffer(buffer):
    header_len = ctypes.sizeof(CommonMessageHeader)
    if header_len > len(buffer):
        raise ValueError(-1, "Buffer smaller than header")
    header = CommonMessageHeader.from_buffer_copy(buffer)
    required_buf_len = header_len + header.data_len
    if required_buf_len > len(buffer):
        raise ValueError(-2, "Buffer smaller than header and data")

    class CommonMessage(ctypes.Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [
            ("header", CommonMessageHeader),
            ("data", ctypes.c_ubyte * header.data_len)
        ]

    return CommonMessage.from_buffer_copy(buffer), required_buf_len


def main():
    print("sizeof(CommonMessageHeader): {:d}".format(ctypes.sizeof(CommonMessageHeader)))
    print("Input buffer len: {:d}\n".format(len(INPUT_BUFFER)))
    inst, inst_len = get_instance_from_buffer(INPUT_BUFFER)
    print_ctypes_instance_info(inst)
    print("\nOutput data as a string ({:d}): [{:s}]".format(len(inst.data), "".join([repr(chr(item))[1:-1] for item in inst.data])))
    print("The rest of the buffer: [{:}]".format(INPUT_BUFFER[inst_len:]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The largest function (*print_ctypes_instance_info*) is just used for printing an object
- I modified a bit your original buffer to actually have something to work with
- *get_instance_from_buffer* is the function that attempts to convert the existing buffer into an *CommonMessage* (which is different than the one in the question which is now *CommonMessageHeader*) instance:

  - It expects a buffer (meaning that it's already read). That is because I didn't want to create a whole server / client app and exchange messages. Actually I got rid of all the socket related code (as the protocol that I'm trying to illustrate doesn't really depend on it). 
    Probably the final implementation should rely on a socket instead of a buffer, and only read the required amount of data from it
  - The *CommonMessage* class is created on the fly for each message (it's not global like *CommonMessageHeader* for example) since *ctypes.Structure._fields_* **can only be set once**
  - If the buffer is too small, *ValueError* is raised
  - The 2<sup>nd</sup> value returned is the number of bytes that were "consumed" for this instance; if for example the input buffer is longer, the remaining ones might belong to the next message

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051086829>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.0.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> sizeof(CommonMessageHeader): 24
> Input buffer len: 51
>
> [<class '__main__.get_instance_from_buffer.<locals>.CommonMessage'>]: <__main__.get_instance_from_buffer.<locals>.CommonMessage object at 0x000002106F1BBBC8>
>     [<class '__main__.CommonMessageHeader'>] header: <__main__.CommonMessageHeader object at 0x000002106F1BBB48>
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>] sof: 4293844428
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>] request_id: 198465918
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>] interface: 11122946
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>] msg_type: 617
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>] response: 1
>         [<class 'ctypes.c_long'>] data_len: 15
>     [<class '__main__.c_ubyte_Array_15'>] data: <__main__.c_ubyte_Array_15 object at 0x000002106F1BBB48>
>         [0]: 1
>         [1]: 2
>         [2]: 3
>         [3]: 4
>         [4]: 5
>         [5]: 68
>         [6]: 117
>         [7]: 109
>         [8]: 109
>         [9]: 121
>         ...
>
> Output data as a string (15): [\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05Dummy Text]
> The rest of the buffer: [b'IGNORED PART']
> ```

Comment: Did this answer your question?