# XML through socket in python

Tags: python, xml, sockets, python-3.6

Good morning,
I've a simple question.
I need a socket that allow a client to send an XML to a server. I've tried to send a simple string `b'simple string just for example'` and everything works fine, but when I try to send an XML (as binary) the server isn't able to write that down. I'll paste my code

**Client**

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket()
socket.connect(("localhost", 54610))
file = open(r"c:\shared\68118.xml", "rb")
stream = file.read(65536)
while stream:
    socket.send(stream)
    stream = file.read(65536) # tried with 1024, 2048
socket.close()
```

**Server**

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('', 54610)
socket.bind(server_address)
socket.listen(1)

while True:
    inbound_stream, address = socket.accept()

    print(address)
    counter = 1
    file = open(r'c:\shared\68118_' + str(counter) + '.xml', 'wb')  # binary
    counter += 1
    while(True):
        stream = inbound_stream.recv(65536)
        while stream:
            file.write(stream)
            stream = inbound_stream.recv(65536) # tried with 1024, 2048
        file.close()
        inbound_stream.close()

socket.close() # TODO NOT REACHABLE
```

the output file is `68118_1.xml` 0Kb with nothing inside

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've just remove the `stream = file.read(65536) # tried with 1024, 2048` from the loop and everything worked fine

Comment: Probably because your file is less than 64kB. But that's not generic. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615187/multiple-send-from-server-to-client-python/30615690#30615690.